# Expectation of geometric random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be geometric random variable with parameter $p$.

How to prove that:

> (1) $E[X-1|X>1] = E[X]$
>
> (2) $E[X^2|X>1] = E[(X+1)^2]$

Author explains the fact below and states it is used to prove (1)
$$P(X-1=k|X>k) = P(X=k).$$

I understood how the fact is true but could not understand how it is used to derive (1)

(2) was stated without explanation. Could someone help in deriving (1) and (2)?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, baba.  With the little you've said, it is hard to surmise what level of understanding you have for such exercises.  Please explain how you have approached these.

Comment: Ad a) $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\cdot P(X-1=k|X >k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \cdot P(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \cdot p \cdot (1-p)^{k-1}=E(X)$$

Comment: @calculus Upvote for solving (1)

Comment: @calculus Guys, I think perhaps it should be $P(X-1=k|X>1) = P(X=k)$. i.e $X \gt 1$ instead of $X \gt k$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think your equation $P(X-1=k\mid X\gt k) = P(X=k)$ is supposed to be (proof below): $$P(X-1=k\mid X\gt 1) = P(X=k).\qquad\qquad (*)$$

(1)

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X-1\mid X\gt 1) &=& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{kP(X-1=k\mid X\gt 1)} \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{kP(X=k)} \qquad\qquad\text{using $(*)$} \\
&=& E(X).
\end{eqnarray*}

(2)

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X^2\mid X\gt 1) &=& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{k^2P(X=k\mid X\gt 1)} \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{k^2P(X=k-1)} \qquad\qquad\text{using $(*)$ with $k-1$ instead of $k$} \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(k+1)^2P(X=k)} \qquad\qquad\text{re-index the sum using $P(X=0)=0$} \\
&=& E((X+1)^2).
\end{eqnarray*}

Note the different mechanism in first line of the two methods. In (1) we treat $X-1$ as a random variable in itself, whereas in (2) we treat $X^2$ as a function of the random variable $X$.

$\\$

Claim: $P(X-1=k\mid X\gt 1) = P(X=k)$.

Firstly, for $k=0$ it's clear that both sides are $0$. So now assume $k\gt 0$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X-1=k\mid X\gt 1) &=& P(X-1=k\cap X\gt 1) / P(X\gt 1) \\
&=& P(X=k+1\cap X\gt 1) / P(X\gt 1) \\
&=& P(X=k+1) / (1-P(X=1)) \\
&=& (1-p)^kp / (1-p) \\
&=& (1-p)^{k-1}p \\
&=& P(X=k).
\end{eqnarray*}